# How SCALA evaluates instance method without having all the values?

Tags: scala

In the following code:

```
object intsets {
  val t1= new NonEmpty(3, new Empty, new Empty) 
//val t2 = t1 incl (4)

  abstract class IntSet {
    def incl(x:Int): IntSet
    def contains(x:Int): Boolean
  }

  class Empty extends IntSet {
    def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
    def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, new Empty, new Empty)
    override def toString = "."
  }

  class NonEmpty (elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
    def contains(x: Int):Boolean =
      if (x < elem) return left.contains(x)
      else if (x > elem) return right.contains(x)
      else true

    def incl(x:Int):IntSet =
      if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x),right)
      else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
      else this
      override def toString = "{" + left + elem + right + "}"
  }

}
```

I'm a little bit confused about the `NonEmpty` method when we instantiate this class without passing any value for x. For Example, in the second line, where I defended `t1` (which means there is no value for x) the REPL returns`t1: NonEmpty = {.3.}`.

I couldn't figure out if the compiler goes to `def contains(x: Int):Boolean =` or not. looks like it does, but how come without having any value for x?

Comment: "I'm a little bit confused about the NonEmpty method" Did you mean "the NonEmpty *class*" or "the *contains* method"?

Comment: the method that we call when we instantiate the `class NonEmpty`.
`new NonEmpty(3, new Empty, new Empty) `
I don't know if instantiation trigs any method inside the class or not by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

def contains(x: Int) is a method on the class. You will call it with a parameter (x) and it will tell you if that value is present in the set.

new NonEmpty(3, new Empty, new Empty) only runs the constructor. In Scala, the constructor consists of the first line of the class, as well as any code that is not in a def.

This means contains(x: Int) will not be called when the object is constructed.

```
val t1 = new NonEmpty(3, new Empty, new Empty)
t1.contains(1) // should return false
t1.contains(3) // should return true
```

Comment: so basically for my `t1` instance it just returns the toString method form NonEmpty?

Comment: Yes. t1 is an instance of NonEmpty and the REPL will call toString() of NonEmpty. This would be the same as calling println(t1) in Scala code.

Comment: So if I want to call a method on my instance I do `t1.contains(1)`? Sweet!! Thank you.

Comment: Notice, the way toString in NonEmpty is written it *will* call the toStrings of left and right too.